# Show that $T$ has an invariant subspace of dimension $j$ for each $j=1,2,\ldots \dim V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Suppose that $V$ is a complex vector space and $T:V\to V$ is linear.Show that $T$ has an invariant subspace of dimension $j$ for each $j=1,2,\ldots \dim V$.
>
> > What happens if $V$ is a real vector space ?

**Attempt**:
If $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb C$ then the characteristic polynomial of $T$ has a root which will be an eigen value say $\lambda$ corresponding to eigen value $v_0$.  Then the $\text{span}\{v_0\}$ is a $1-$ dimensional invariant subspace of $T$.

The same holds for $V$ to be  a vector space over $\Bbb R$ if $\dim V$ is odd.

But I can't proceed further.Any hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: Tried@Mnifldz; But if I assume existence of a n-1 dimensional subspace how does it guarantee existence of $n$ dimensional subspace(invariant)

Comment: " The invariant subspace is the subspace W that maps within itself, not TW, i.e. whatever that subspace maps to. When asked about the dimension of the invariant subspace, it means the dimension of W, not TW. That said, TW will actually be another subspace invariant under T, but it will (in general) be a different, smaller invariant subspace than W." - Theo Bendit

Answer (score 2):

Over the complex numbers every linear operator can be brougth in upper triangular form. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281833/matrix-similarity-upper-triangular-matrix). You can also think about the Jordan-Normal-Form if you're familiar with it. Now in this form the matrix leaves the spaces $\{e_1\}\subset\{e_1,e_2\}\subset\ldots\subset\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ invariant. By $e_i$ I mean the canonical basis.

In the real numbers this is no longer true. For example think about a rotation in 2 dimensions which doesn't leave any subspace (except zero) invariant.