# Diagonalization of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I'm trying to prove that  every symmetric matrix is diagonalizable. I know that there are already many answers regarding this question, but I just want to check out whether my approach is correct or not. After some searching, I found some clues to my problem ([Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281833/matrix-similarity-upper-triangular-matrix)). Based on Tunococ's answer, I want to prove the following : For every symmetric matrix (with real entries), there exists an orthogonal matrix B and a diagonal matrix D such that $$ B^{T}AB = D $$ Let's use induction on orders of $A$. For $1 \times 1$ matrix (which is symmetric), this is trivial. Suppose that this result is true for $k \times k$ symmetric matrix ($k\geq1$). Let $A$ be a 
 $(k+1) \times (k+1)$ symmetric matrix. Let $\lambda$ be any eigenvalue of $A$ and $v$ be an associated eigenvector. Since an eigenvector multiplied by any nonzero scalar is still an eigenvector, we can assume that $\left \| v \right \|=1$. By Gram-Schmidt process, we can obtain an orthonormal basis $\{v, w_2, \ldots, w_{k+1}\}$ of  $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$. Let C be an orthogonal matrix defined by $$
C =
\begin{bmatrix}
| & | & \ldots & |\\
v & w_2 & \ldots & w_{k+1} \\
| & | & \ldots & |
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then, after some computation, we obtain
$$C^{T}AC =\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & O_{1 \times k} \\ 
O_{k \times 1} & F
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Here, $F$ is a $k \times k$ symmetric matrix. By the induction hypothesis, there exists an orthogonal matrix $G$ and a diagonal matrix $H$ such that $G^{T}FG=H$. Let $$J =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & O_{1 \times k} \\ 
O_{k \times 1} & G
\end{bmatrix}.$$ Since $G$ is an orthogonal matrix, $J$ is also an orthogonal matrix. By computation, we obtain $$(CJ)^{T}A(CJ)=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & O_{1 \times k} \\ 
O_{k \times 1} & H
\end{bmatrix}.$$ Note that since $C$ and $J$ are orthogonal matrices, their product $CJ$ is also an orthogonal matrix.

Is this argument correct?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to explain why you can find an eigenpair $(\lambda, v)$.

Comment: Umm.... Since characteristic equation is polynomial equation of order (k+1), equation always has roots.... Choose any root(eigenvalue), and thus we can find an associated eigenvector.... Also, since A is symmetric, roots are always real.

Comment: No, $1 + x^2$ has no real root.

Comment: When A is symmetric, if there is an eigenvalue, then it is real. (using $x^* A x = (Ax)^* x$ ).

Comment: I mean all the roots of the characteristic polynomial of a symmetric matrix are real numbers... So.... I think $1+x^2$ is not our candidate....

Comment: Look here http://control.ucsd.edu/mauricio/courses/mae280a/lecture11.pdf  (Proof of bullet 2).

Comment: Oh, thanks! And it is always possible to find such eigen-pair you mentioned on your answer, right?? I got little confused... I just want to make sure.....

Comment: Once you have one eigenpair, the rest of your proof is good.

Comment: And...Does such pair always exist??